# .Net 6 WindowsForm, calling WCF function with WSFederationHttpBinding

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core

I have a web application (.Net framework 4.x) which makes a call to a WCF service. The binding endpoint, endpointBehavior and binding are all configured in the web.config and this has been working for some time.

I have a .Net 6 WinForm application in which I need to make a call to the same service. I've created a Ws2007HttpBinding and am making a call to the service but am getting '*an error occurred when verifying security for the message*'.

The bit that I need to work out is that the original behavior issuedTokenType is set to SAMLV2.0 and uses WS-Trust.

I've added the System.ServiceModel.Federation namespace and am trying to use a WSFederationHttpBinding, but working out out the different settings required (as compared to what was in the old web.config binding) is proving interesting.

Does anyone have an example code/documentation?

Regards

Comment: Can't you add a WCF service to your WinForms project?

Comment: no - in short. I need to do it programmatically as this is the first of many services that I need to add.   The bit that is holding me up at the moment is setting the IssuerMetadataAddress.  In debug I can see in the wsTrustParameters the setting is there and null, but it does not appear to have an accessor that I can find.

Comment: Also, the built in service discovery tool does not appear to work with federated services.